# URI.parse(url).open not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

So I just added the option to upload images by url using this action

```
@stock = Stock.create
  @stock.url = params[:url]
  @stock.image = URI.parse(  params[:url]  ).open
  @stock.user = current_user
  @stock.save
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
```

and it's working in development but not in heroku. I'm using paperclip to save he images on AWS.

I'm not getting any errors too. I tried without .open it worked in development but not in heroku. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Since Paperclip 3.1.4 you don't need to call `open` on that. `URI.parse(url)` should suffice.

Comment: It's working now, I changed the CORS

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim thanks, changed it